Склонение иностранных топонимов
Насколько мне известно, мнения насчёт этого расходятся, но можно же выделить какие-нибудь общепринятые нормы, руководствоваться которыми не зазорно?
Например, можно ли склонять Колд-Спрингс? Можно ли подобное провернуть с похожими названиями городов (допустим, Варегово/Элко) и вообще с любыми? Или всё-таки лучше не склонять?

Колд-Спрингс


Колда-Спрингса


Колду-Спрингсу


Колд-Спрингс


Колдом-Спрингсом


Колде-Спрингсе


"Иноязычные названия, оканчивающиеся на согласный, обычно не склоняются в функции приложения.." - https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kak-sklonyat-geograficheskie-nazvaniya

Лучше ситуативно решать. Например, переводчики склоняют вымышленный город Кастл-Рок (р.п. Кастл-Рока), и выглядит это органично. В реальной жизни Лос-Анджелес склоняется повсеместно. А вот Колд-Спрингс склонять не хочется, т.к. получилось бы неуклюже

Общепринятые нормы, конечно же, есть.
Склонение географических названий

Географические названия не склоняются в следующих случаях:
<...>
• первая часть сложносоставных иноязычных топонимов, как правило, не склоняется: в Алма-Ате, под Буэнос-Айресом, из Йошкар-Олы;
• сложные наименования типа Пер-Лашез, Майн-Милл, Пуэрто-Монт...

Еще примеры: в Лос-Анжелесе, из Нью-Йорка, к Улан-Батору, в Лас-Вегасе, в Баден-Бадене...
Такие рекомендации означают, что первое слово неизменно, а вот второе чаще всего склоняется. Редкие знаменитые исключения иногда включаются в орфографические словари.
Пер-Лашез повезло, оно там есть, с пометкой нескл.
В других случаях, думаю, нужно ориентироваться на практику письма.
Френсин Паскаль. Любовные письма:

Лила и Джессика переглянулись.
— Это ты о том парне, которого встретила в Олд-Спрингсе? — оживилась Лила. — Как там его имя?
— Адам, — мечтательно произнесла Кэролайн. — Только не в Олд-Спрингсе, а в Колд-Спрингсе, — поправила она Лилу. — Он мне звонил сегодня утром, — добавила она, застенчиво уставясь в песок.

Всего зафиксировано около 200 активных пожаров. Погибли минимум семь человек: три жертвы в округе Бьютт (Калифорния), две в округе Мэрион (Орегон), одна в городе Медфорд (Орегон) и ребенок в Колд-Спрингсе (штат Вашингтон) (из статьи).
В этом предложении интересно то, что в сложном названии не изменяются первые две части, а склоняется только последняя:
Сам биолог говорил, что деньги от продажи он передаст нескольким американским университетам и лаборатории в Колд-Спрингс-Харборе (из статьи).
